# Java String.replaceAll method to sanitize phone numbers

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I have databasefield called TelephoneName. In this field, I got different formats of telephone number.

What I need now is to seperate them into countrycode and subscribernumber.

For example, I saw a telephone number +49 (0)711 / 61947-xx.

I want to remove all the slash,brackets,minus,space. The result could be +49 (countrycode) and 071161947**(subsribernumber).

How can I do that with replaceAll method?

`replaceAll("//()-","")` is that correct?

The thing is I got a lot of unformatted telephone number such as:
+49 04261 85120
+32027400050
It is different to apply every telephone number with same algorithms

Comment: If you want to capture the country code and the subscriber number you might want to use a regex instead.

Answer (score 8):

The `replaceAll` method takes a regular expression as argument. To remove everything except digits and `+`, you could thus do

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9+]", "")
```

---

Here's a more complete example that also figures out the country code (based on the index of the `(` symbol):

```
String str = "+49 (0)711 / 61947-12";

int lpar = str.indexOf('(');
String countryCode = str.substring(0, lpar).trim();
String subscriber  = str.substring(lpar).trim();

subscriber = subscriber.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

System.out.println(countryCode);  // prints +49
System.out.println(subscriber);   // prints 07116194712
```

---

> `replaceAll("//()-","")` is that correct?

No, not quite. That will remove all `//-` substrings. To remove those *characters* you need to put them in `[...]`, like this: `replaceAll("[/()-]", "")` (and `/` does not need to be escaped).

Comment: Note that you might want to get the country code out first since country codes vary in length.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of replaceAll() is a regex pattern, so what you want to do is make it match  all non digits (and +). You can do this using the "[^...]" (not one of...) construct :

```
mystring.replaceAll("[^0-9+]", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that doesn't work.

`ReplaceAll()` [Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

So your expression would replace all instances in the number that look like `/()'` with an empty space.

You need to do something like

```
String output = "+49 (0)711 / 61947-xx".replaceAll("[//()-]","");
```

The square brackets make it a regex character class ('Either slash or open bracket or close bracket or hypen'), rather than a literal ('slash followed by open bracket followed by close bracket followed by hypen.').

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you need the two slashes in java to escape the slash character? (So this is an escape for Java rather than for Regex.) Then, if you wanted an escaped slash in Regex, you'd need four slashes `////` in your string.

Comment: I think you're mixing it up with backslash.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done simply by using :

```
s=s.replace("/","");
s=s.replace("(","");
s=s.replace(")","");
```

Then substring it to get country code.

Comment: He also wrote whitespace so don't forget space, tab, new line, carriage return, form feed, vertical tab... I think you get my point ;)